# disable NAT in openvpn

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, nat

I'm having a similar problem to this: 
[OpenVPN without NAT](https://superuser.com/questions/960411/openvpn-without-nat)

Seems it wasn't answered yet.

Description of my situation: 
I have an openvpn server on network A which another admin installed before he left the company, now several users and servers connect to that openvpn server to access network A and get NATed so all requests from vpn users/servers have the source address from the openvpn server.

Now I need a server on network A to access one of the openvpn clients/servers and want to disable NAT in openvpn to expose the "vpn internal" IP addresses of these clients and servers.

I know that I need to add a route on Network A to access the vpn network, that's clear to me but I cannot see how to disable NAT in openvpn, also there are no IPtables rules present so some openvpn internal NAT mechanism seems to be in use.

Which options I need to check to disable NAT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the OpenVPN server there must be a rule like

```
        iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

You can find it with

```
      iptables-t nat -L -n -v
```

You must suppress this rule.

If, as you claim (but did you run

```
      iptables -t nat -L -n -v
```

to double-check there are no iptables rules at at play?), the only other possibility is that natting is done through the `iproute2` suite. Do

```
    cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

jot down the names of the table you have, then issue

```
     ip route table TABLE_NAME | grep ^nat
```

and see whether you can find some output. If you do, it means that the packet headers are rewritten by the `iproute2` command `ip route add nat ..`. All you need to do is to delete the routing table in question.

These are the two possibilities, *tertium non datur*.

Now you need to add a rule to the router to route packets for the OpenVPN subnet 10.0.0.0/24 via the OpenVPNserver (let's assume it has IP address192.168.0.127). If the router were a Linux machine the following command would do:

```
       ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 via 192.168.0.127
```

Most routers, like Cisco's , have an `Advanced routing` capability, to be found in theri GUI. You should use that to specify the route above.

Comment: As I said there are no IPtables rules present on the openvpn server.

I monitored network traffic using tcpdump on the openvpn server, when looking at the tun device of openvpn, I can see traffic from source address of the vpn-client tunnel IP and destination IP is on network A.

When looking at the network A interface of the vpn server, I can see the same packets with source IP of the openvpn server instead of the tunnel-ip of that vpn user.

Any ideas which parameter to check?

Comment: @Hans Have you looked at the output of `iptables -t nat -L -n -v` on the OpenVPN server?

Comment: @Hans Pls re-read my post for new info.

Comment: Thank you, I did not check iptables -t nat -L -n -v, only iptables -L (as I do usually) and it did not show the nat table (-t nat).

Now I found that rule which was present, then I searched in /etc where this is configured and found that the guy added it to /etc/rc.local 

I removed the nat rule (iptables -t nat -F) and now tcpdump shows the traffic as expected :)